# Can I set the DCOM System-Wide Default Security Authentication Level with a Group Policy?

Tags: windows, dcom

I would like to raise the System-Wide Default Security Authentication Level of DCOM on multiple machines from "Connect" to "Package Privacy". In the GUI, you find this setting when you start dcomcnfg, visit the properties of "My Computer" and go to the page "Default Properties". This is also described in the following article: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/com/setting-machine-wide-security-using-dcomcnfg#setting-system-wide-default-authentication-level

When I start the group policy editor, I only find policies for the limits and defaults which you can set on the "Default COM Security" page. But this is not what I need.

So is there a way to set the authentication level via a group policy?

Answer (score 0):

If the value will be the same on every system, the following registry value may be set with a Registry policy preference:

Key: HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Ole
Value: LegacyAuthenticationLevel
Value Data: 6
Value Type: REG_DWORD